# Why doesn't the policy check work in the middleware?

Tags: php, laravel

I have routes

```
Route::middleware('auth')->group(function (){
    //resource controller for products
    Route::apiResource("products",ProductController::class);
    //additional routes for cook processes
    Route::prefix("products")->group(function (){
        Route::get("{product}/{cookProcess}",[CookProcessController::class,"show"]);
/*My problem is bellow*/
        Route::post("/{product}/cookProcessCreate",[CookProcessController::class,"store"])->middleware('can:create,cookProcess');
        Route::delete("{product}/{cookProcess}",[CookProcessController::class,"destroy"])->middleware('can:delete,cookProcess');
        Route::patch("{product}/{cookProcess}",[CookProcessController::class,"update"])->middleware('can:update,cookProcess');
    });
    });
```

The issue with `Route::post("/{product}/cookProcessCreate")`. When I apply middleware to it, the server returns a 403 status when trying to interact with it. I logged the corresponding policy - the create method doesn't work at all.

Policy

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Models\Product;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;
use App\Models\CookProcess;
use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class CookProcessPolicy
{
    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user): bool
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the model.
     */
    public function view(User $user, CookProcess $cookProcess): bool
    {
        Log::debug("process policyview launched");
        return Auth::check();
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create models.
     */
    public function create(User $user): bool
    {
        Log::debug("process policy create launched");
        return Auth::check();
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the model.
     */
    public function update(User $user, CookProcess $cookProcess): bool
    {
        Log::debug("process policyupdate launched");
        return $user->hasPermissionTo('edit notes');
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the model.
     */
    public function delete(User $user, CookProcess $cookProcess): bool
    {
        Log::debug("process policydelete launched");
        return $user->hasPermissionTo('delete notes');
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can restore the model.
     */
    public function restore(User $user, CookProcess $cookProcess): bool
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can permanently delete the model.
     */
    public function forceDelete(User $user, CookProcess $cookProcess): bool
    {
        //
    }
}
```

grateful for any help.

However, if I use authorization without middleware `($this->authorize('create',CookProcess::class))`, everything works fine. Other routes are fine and being logged.
for route testing i use PHPunit with this test

```
 {
        $this->seed(PermissionsTableSeeder::class);
        $this->seed(RolesTableSeeder::class);
        $user=User::factory()->create();
        $user->assignRole('site_user');
        $this->actingAs($user);
        $product=Product::factory()->create();
        $processData = [
            "name"=>'testname',
            "duration"=>fake()->numberBetween(1,10),
            "cookPresenceInterval"=>fake()->numberBetween(0,5),
            "description"=>fake()->text(50),
            "product_id"=>$product->id
        ];
        $response=$this->post("/api/products/".$product->id . '/cookProcessCreate',$processData);
        $response->assertStatus(200);
        $createdProcess = CookProcess::where('name','testname')->first();
        $this->assertNotNull($createdProcess);
    }
```

And controller is

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //$this->authorize('create',CookProcess::class);
        $validData = $request->validate([
            "name"=>"string|required|unique:products|",
            'product_id'=>"integer|exists:products,id",
            "duration"=>"required|numeric",
            "cookPresenceInterval"=>"required|numeric",
            "description"=>"required|string|min:20"
        ]);
        $newCookProcess = CookProcess::create($validData);
        return response()->json(['message'=>"Cook process created successfully id - $newCookProcess"]);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(Product $product,CookProcess $cookProcess)
    {
        return response()->json(["cookProcess"=>$cookProcess]);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request,Product $product, CookProcess $cookProcess)
    {
        $cookProcess->update($request->all());
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Cook process updated successfully']);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(CookProcess $cookProcess)
    {
        $cookProcess->delete();
        return response()->json(['message'=>'Cook process has been deleted']);
    }
}
```

I'm completely baffled about what could be causing this issue

Comment: can you show your Controller method for that route? also one you are using a route parameter name and the other you are using the classname for the mdoel

Comment: your `create` method of the policy doesn't take a model instance ... so there would be no route parameter to pass to it ... "Actions That Don't Require Models" : https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#middleware-actions-that-dont-require-models

Comment: @lagbox , i cant believe i miss it! I REALLY have read this doc page several times. Thnx a lot. Write this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are dealing with a policy method that doesn't require a Model instance, such as your `create` method, you can just pass the FQCN as the parameter so it knows which Policy to use:

```
...->middleware('can:create,App\Models\CookProcess')
```

You can also simplify this and call the `can` method on the Route that is created instead of manually defining the `can` middleware to use:

```
use App\Models\CookProcess;

...

...->can('create', CookProcess::class);
```

This gives you the benefit of passing actual arguments and not just a string that gets parsed down into parameters. In the above example we use the class constant to give us the FQCN.

[Laravel 10.x Docs - Security - Authorization - Via Middleware - Actions that Do Not Require Models](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#middleware-actions-that-dont-require-models)

Comment: @kentavr16 I posted an answer, if it works for you feel free to accept it